# How to set xAxis minimum and maximum values on Highstock?

Tags: highcharts

I have a little problem with my HighStock Charts. I am plotting data from a database which returns speed values of a car in a certain period of time (3 days).

For example, I want to plot the speed values between 1st January at 00:00 and 3rd January at 00:00, but I just have values on the 2nd of January...the other days the car was parked.

What is happening is that highstock auto adapts the xAxis for period where there is available data, in this case 2nd January...it doesn´t show me the other 2 days where the car was parked.
Is there a way to set a fixed start date and end date on xAxis? I've tried to find something in the documentation but so far nothing worked.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the "min" and "max" attributes of the xAxis:

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.min

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.max

If you specify values, it should not automatically calculate them for you.

If that doesn't work, could you please post a http://JSfiddle.net with your code so I can take a look?

Comment: I've tried what you said but with no sucess! Here you have the JSFiddle as requested. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Allmighty11/BFgkU/

I need to set a fixed date (18-20 January), so 1 day before and 1 day after the day where there is some data. Should I use TickPositionar 1 second? Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmmmm...have you tried passing in null values for the entire range? Don't pass zeros, pass null if there is no data for the given time.

Comment: Also, I noticed you have ``selected: 4`` for the rangeSelector set, be sure to change that to 5 for 3 days as well.

Comment: Ok, I've changed that! Thanks. 
The thing is that I what to avoid to generate zeros or nulls in my data array since it will decrease performance. It doesn't make sense to generate data for non-existing values. Best way should be to set a fixed interval and match it with timestamp values generated in my data.

Comment: Yes, with null and zeros it worked ok. But it generates a huge amount of data on my array which I think it is not necessary. There should be another way around...

Comment: I've managed a way to make it work! Just added a "start date" and "end date" to my array and set ordinal to false. However another problem comes up! The resolution of my graph become really bad...do you know a way to higher it up? http://jsfiddle.net/Allmighty11/BFgkU/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set ordinal as false http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal or use tickPositioner to define ticks positions http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: I've tried in the way you said it...but is didn't work out for me.
Please, check jsfiddle.net/Allmighty11/BFgkU so you can visualize my problem. Thanks